# Closing clients on a multithreaded chat server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i am currently working on a chat server as a project an need a bit of help. i have a multithreaded chat server where i want the clients to be able to close their chat window without crashing the server because it loses connection. So far so good. i have a working gui, and when i have a single client logged in to the server it works just fine to close the window and so closing the clientIOProcessor without the server crashing. 
However, when i have multiple clients logged in to the server and want to close one of them the hole thing crashes

here is the ClientIOProcessor:

```
public class ClientIOProcessor extends Object implements Runnable, InputListener {

    private ObjectInput socketInput;
    private ObjectOutput socketOutput;
    private boolean keepRunning;
    private ClientModelDistributor assignedModelDistributor;
    private MessageImplementation currentMessage;
    private UserHub userHub;

    public ClientIOProcessor(ClientModelDistributor _assignedModelDistributor, ObjectInput _socketInput,
            ObjectOutput _socketOutput) {

        this.assignedModelDistributor = _assignedModelDistributor;
        this.socketInput = _socketInput;
        this.socketOutput = _socketOutput;

        assignedModelDistributor.getInputHandler().registerInputListener(this);
        keepRunning = true;
    }

    public ClientIOProcessor(ClientLoginProcessor clientLoginProcessor, UserHub userHub) {
        assignedModelDistributor = clientLoginProcessor.assignedModelDistributor;
        socketInput = clientLoginProcessor.socketInput;
        socketOutput = clientLoginProcessor.socketOutput;

        assignedModelDistributor.getInputHandler().registerInputListener(this);
        assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().addIncomingMessageListener(userHub);
        keepRunning = true;
        this.userHub = userHub;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
            currentMessage = null;
            currentMessage = buildMessageFromInput();
            if(currentMessage == null) return;

            switch (currentMessage.getMessageType()) {
            case CHATMSG:
                assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(currentMessage);
                break;
            case USRJOINED:
                assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(currentMessage);
                break;
            case USRLEFT:
                assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(currentMessage);
                break;
            case TERMINATE:
                this.terminateConnection();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void terminateConnection() {
        keepRunning = false;
        assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().removeIncomingMessageListener(this.userHub);
        assignedModelDistributor.getInputHandler().removeInputListener(this);
        try {
            socketInput.close();
            socketOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      System.exit(0);
    }

    private MessageImplementation buildMessageFromInput() {

        MessageImplementation messageSentByServer = null;
        try {
            messageSentByServer = (MessageImplementation) socketInput.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return messageSentByServer;
    }

    /**
     * This method can be used to send <code>messages</code> to the server.
     * 
     * @param message
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void send(Message message) throws IOException {

        try {
            socketOutput.writeObject(message);
            socketOutput.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called whenever the user enters input to this
     * <code>InputListener</code>'s corresponding <code>InputHandler</code>.
     */
    @Override
    public void inputEntered(String input) {

        try {
            send(assignedModelDistributor.buildUserMessage(input));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

the clientIO processor gets the TERMINATE message from the server and calls the terminateConnection() Method to end the Streams.

Here is the ServerIOProcessor:

```
public class ServerIOProcessor implements Runnable, IncomingMessageListener {

    private ServerModelDistributor assignedModelDistributor;
    private User assignedUser;
    private boolean keepRunning;
    private ObjectInputStream socketInput;
    private ObjectOutputStream socketOutput;
    private MessageImplementation currentMessage;
    private final String SYSTEM = "System";

    public ServerIOProcessor(User _assignedUser, ObjectOutputStream _socketOutput, ObjectInputStream _socketInput,
            ServerModelDistributor _assignedModelDistributor) {
        assignedUser = _assignedUser;
        socketInput = _socketInput;
        socketOutput = _socketOutput;
        assignedModelDistributor = _assignedModelDistributor;
        keepRunning = true;

        assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().addIncomingMessageListener(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
            currentMessage = null;
            currentMessage = buildMessageFromInput();

            switch (currentMessage.getMessageType()) {
            case CHATMSG:
                assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(currentMessage);
                break;
            case NEWTASK:
                createNewTask();
                break;
            case TASKASSGNMNT:
                assignTaskToUser();
                break;
            case NEWLEADER:
                determineLeaderOfTeam();
                break;
            case ADDTEAM:
                addTeam();
                break;
            case RMVTEAM:
                removeTeam();
                break;
            case ADDTEAMMEMBER:
                addUserToTeam();
                break;
            case RMVTEAMMEMBER:
                removeUserFromTeam();
                break;
            case JOINTEAM:
                joinTeam();
                break;
            case LEAVETEAM:
                leaveTeam();
                break;
            case EDITDETAILS:
                editUserDetails();
                break;
            case TERMINATE:
                assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(currentMessage);
                letClientLeaveServer();
                break;
            default:
                send(newSystemMessage(MessageType.ERROR));
                System.out.println("An error occured in one of the server's active IO processes.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void createNewTask() {

    }

    private void assignTaskToUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void determineLeaderOfTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void addTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void removeTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void addUserToTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void removeUserFromTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void joinTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void leaveTeam() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void editUserDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void letClientLeaveServer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().removeIncomingMessageListener(this);
        try {
            socketInput.close();
            socketOutput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        keepRunning = false;
    }

    private MessageImplementation buildMessageFromInput() {

        MessageImplementation messageSentByUser = null;
        try {
            messageSentByUser = (MessageImplementation) socketInput.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return messageSentByUser;
    }

    private MessageImplementation newSystemMessage(MessageType msgtype) {

        return new MessageImplementation(SYSTEM, msgtype);
    }

    //TODO Check expected purpose of this method.
    /**
     * This method is called whenever a <code>Message</code> is entered to the
     * corresponding <code>IncomingMessageHandler</code>.
     */
    @Override
    public void messageEntered(Message message) {
        // assignedModelDistributor.getIncomingMessageHandler().enterMessage(message);
        try {
            socketOutput.writeObject(message);
            socketOutput.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes the given <code>Message</code> to the Socket's
     * <code>ObjectInputStream</code>.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void send(Message message) {

        try {
            socketOutput.writeObject(message);
            socketOutput.flush();
        } catch (Exception r) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            r.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the important part here is the letClientLeaveServer() method to end the streams here as well. however, i think this is the wrong way, because i think this ends the Input/Ouput Streams for all logged in Clients.

The ServerSocket it self is initialized in another class ConnectionProcessor which starts the Socket on a given port and accepts it. then the connectionProcessor starts the serverLogInProcessor which starts a new Thread for the serverIOProcessor.

Here the ConnectionProcessor:

```
public class ConnectionProcessor implements Runnable {

    private ServerModelDistributor assignedModelDistributor;
    private boolean keepRunning;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int assignedPort;

    public ConnectionProcessor(int _assignedPort, ServerModelDistributor _assignedModelDistributor) {

        assignedModelDistributor = _assignedModelDistributor;
        assignedPort = _assignedPort;
        keepRunning = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(assignedPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (keepRunning) {
            if(serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(assignedPort);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Socket socketCreatedForLoginProcess = serverSocket.accept();
                serverSocket.close();

                Thread serverLoginProcessor = new Thread(
                        new ServerLoginProcessor(this, socketCreatedForLoginProcess, assignedModelDistributor),
                        "loginProcess");
                serverLoginProcessor.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you recreate the ServerSocket after each accept?

Comment: Do you account for unplanned disconnections where the TERMINATE message is not sent? Normally you just catch the exception which you automatically get when a client disconnects. I think you'll catch that in `buildMessageFromInput()`.

Comment: * This Runnable is started by the <code>ServerLauncher</code> and is used to
 * handle incoming Socket connections by accepting requests on an established
 * <code>ServerSocket</code> starting a new Thread for each connection which
 * handles the login process.

Comment: this is the the given information for the connectionprocessor. 
isnt it necessary to have a connection for each client so that you can terminate each connection whithout affecting the others?

Comment: And no, i have not watched at the case you mentioned. i think youre right though, maybe we will implement some case for that

Comment: _"isnt it necessary to have a connection for each client so that you can terminate each connection whithout affecting the others?"_ Yes, `accept()` returns a Socket instance for the newly connected client which you're already using. You can keep the ServerSocket.

Comment: If you handle unplanned disconnection correctly, you shouldn't need the TERMINATE message at all. If that doesn't solve the server crash please edit the question and show the specific exception that you get.